# jQuery .stop() with UI .toggle() slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I prefer the effect of jQuery UI's `.toggle()` animation with the 'slide' effect over jQuery's slideToggle animation. However, it seems that the `.stop()` function does not behave the same between the two options:

```
jQuery('div').stop().toggle('slide', { 
  direction: 'up',
}, 200);

jQuery('div').stop().slideToggle();
```

I'm calling these functions on hover, and when the element is hovered on/off quickly the animation using toggle() is broken. Here's an example - try hovering on/off each button quickly to see the difference - https://jsfiddle.net/v87r1pxb/1/

Is it possible to replcate the effect of `.stop().slideToggle()` using jQuery UI's slide effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you call `stop()` with no parameters in the jQueryUI version, hence the same slide animation is called again on `mouseleave` but from the current position of the elements. This means that the `div` is moved up higher above the button to a point where it's no longer visible.

To fix this use `stop(true, true)`. This stops the animation, clears all queued animations on the element and also put the element in the state it would have been if the full animation had been allowed to complete, like this:

```
jQuery('#ui-button').hover(function() {
    jQuery('#ui').stop(true, true).toggle('slide', {
        direction: 'up',
    }, 200);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/v87r1pxb/2/)

Regardless of this fix, I would use the standard jQuery method anyway.

Comment: I can't get this to work in this scenario - https://jsfiddle.net/v87r1pxb/3/ - I have a feeling it has to do with redefining the `$subMenu` variable but I have not found a solution yet. This also shows why I prefer the UI toggle animation - it slides as a panel rather than revealing the content.

Comment: The issue there is due to your use of `children()` instead of `find()`: https://jsfiddle.net/v87r1pxb/4/

Comment: Interesting, I thought the only difference was how deep it looks for a matched element. Do you have an explanation as to why that makes the difference.

Comment: The plain old jQuery version is still much better though: https://jsfiddle.net/v87r1pxb/5/. IMO jQueryUI isn't very good. It does a lot of things very rigidly which makes it a pain to amend, especially with regard to the UI. There are much, much better alternatives, not least of all Bootstrap.

Comment: What effect in Bootstrap mimic's jQuery UI's slide effect? Just to clarify - I'm looking for the entire panel to appear as if it's sliding down rather than simply being revealed like in the plain jQuery slideDown.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have any animation effects like that. To achieve what you want it's all down to how the element is structured and displayed with its HTML and CSS. If you need guidance on that I would start a new question.